# Copying files containing particular key words, and moving them to another folder, with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have stored file paths which match particular text which I am looking for, in a variable called $filepaths. Now, what I want to do is copy those files, which match content I'm looking for, and put them into a new folder, with say, file path: C:\newfolder

I have written the following simple scripts, neither of which work:

1.

```
Copy-Item -path $match in $filepaths -Destination C:\newfolder -Recurse
```

2.

```
foreach($match in $filepaths)
{
    Copy-Item -path $match -Destination C:\newfolder
}
```

I converted the file paths into a table format using `$filepaths = $files | Format-Table * -wrap` (which works) - but perhaps this is what is causing the problem?

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: They should both work with one change in the first one. `Copy-Item -path $filepaths -Destination C:\newfolder `. Do you not get any errors? Are you _sure_ that `$filepaths` contains the data that it should and it is not null

Comment: I converted the file paths into a table format, i.e. using $filepaths = $files | Format-Table * -wrap [which works] - but perhaps this is what is causing the problem? If so, what is the best format for the file paths to be in?

Answer (score 2):

AHHHH the `Format-....` problem

Never use `Format-Anything` if you intend to use the data again. You have corrupted the object you had by saving the table format.

I don't know what `$files` is but if it is output from `Get-ChildItem` then leave it be and you will be fine. Same goes if it was just a string array.

Look at the following examples

## Proper Output

`Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Get-Member` would give you a potential mix of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo` objects.

## "Corrupted" Output

`Get-ChildItem c:\temp | Format-Table | Get-Member` would give you objects like the following. There are more than this but point is the original objects are gone.

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData
 ....
```